# how would i get the headline to fade in and move up very slightly on page load with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How would i get the headline to fade in and move up slightly after the user lands on the home page using css. a good example of what i would like to achieve is on this website http://www.mikeinghamdesign.com. Understand it can be done using translateY but I have never used this before.

HTML

```
<div class="homepage">
<div class="headline">
<h1><span>WELCOME</span></h1>
</div>
<div class="subheadline">
<h1><span>To the home of</span></h1></div><div class="subheadline"><h1><span>Multimedia Journalist</span></h1></div>
<div class="subheadline"><h1><span>Dan Morris</span></h1></div>
<a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll" id="contactlink">Let's talk</a>
<div class="down-link"><a class="w-downlink" href="#about"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.homepage {
height: 650px;
width: 100%;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-image: url(../images/25H.jpg);
background-attachment: fixed;
float: left;
}

.headline {
height: auto;
width: 75%;
margin-left: 78px;
margin-top: 120px;
margin-right: auto;
font: 200 18px/1.3 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI Light', sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 200;
color: #676767;
text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: You don't need JQuery. Look up CSS webkit animations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to just use a CSS animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/xdbpwoLa/

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.headline {
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn .25s ease-in .5s both;
    animation: fadeIn .25s ease-in .5s both;
}
```

Comment: Browser compatibility reference: [CSS3 Animation](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)

Comment: how would i make it fade in and move up slightly? Like on this page? http://www.mikeinghamdesign.com

Comment: @iamdanmorris You can add a translateY to the keyframe.

Comment: I've never used that before. Basically i want the headline to fade in and move up slightly like in the webpage posted how do i apply that with translateY?

Answer (score 1):

```
@keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: 0.2;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
.headline{
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

How it works:

When the headline is loaded, the animation immediately takes effect and causes it to fade from 20% to 100% opacity. We define an animation named `fade`, then apply it to `.headline`.

Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ycfm5oc0/1/) link where you can test this.